# A "Library"-folder appeared in my Applications folder on Mac, should that be there?

Tags: finder

My Mac running Ventura is showing a Library folder inside the Applications folder that has no permissions to open it (red circle with dash sign on it). I shows zero bytes. What's it for and how did it get there and can I delete it somehow?
[image]

Comment: Did you recently install some software?  If so, what was it?

Comment: What does the command `sudo ls -la /Applications/Library` show?

Comment: It's likely a scripting error, that has created this folder in the wrong place. (As Allan says - have you installed something recently?) It's certainly not normal for a Library folder to be there.

Comment: It's been there for many months and don't remember if I installed software. I was going to delete it but thought I'd check with everyone before just in case it's something new. I'll use a rm command in Terminal or login as Root to delete it. Thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the folder using Terminal's rm command. I then restarted and so far it hasn't come back:)